# Pandas `*** TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous` When All Boolean Columns Have Values?

Tags: python, pandas

## Error

```
tests/test_flatten_rates_etl.py:153:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
pandas/_libs/testing.pyx:52: in pandas._libs.testing.assert_almost_equal
    ???
pandas/_libs/testing.pyx:159: in pandas._libs.testing.assert_almost_equal
    ???
pandas/_libs/testing.pyx:105: in pandas._libs.testing.assert_almost_equal
    ???
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
>   ???
E   TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous

pandas/_libs/missing.pyx:388: TypeError
```

## What I'm Looking For

I'm looking either for help finding the columns with the `NA`s OR I'm looking for someone that knows what my actual issue is and can explain how to fix this

## PDB Sessions

```
(Pdb) actual_df.select_dtypes(include=["bool", "boolean", bool])
   service_level__is_trackable  service_level__available_shippo  object_custom_logic_applied  is_trackable  includes_insurance  available_shippo  address_from__is_residential  address_from__validate  address_to__is_residential  address_to__validate  address_return__is_residential  address_return__validate  shipment__bi_state_is_test
0                         True                            False                         True         False               False             False                         False                   False                       False                 False                           False                     False                       False
1                         True                             True                         True         False               False             False                         False                   False                       False                 False                           False                     False                       False
2                         True                             True                         True         False               False             False                         False                   False                       False                 False                           False                     False                       False
3                         True                             True                         True         False               False             False                         False                   False                       False                 False                           False                     False                       False
(Pdb) expected_df.select_dtypes(include=["bool", "boolean", bool])
   service_level__is_trackable  service_level__available_shippo  object_custom_logic_applied  is_trackable  includes_insurance  available_shippo  address_from__is_residential  address_from__validate  address_to__is_residential  address_to__validate  address_return__is_residential  address_return__validate  shipment__bi_state_is_test
0                         True                            False                         True         False               False             False                         False                   False                       False                 False                           False                     False                       False
1                         True                             True                         True         False               False             False                         False                   False                       False                 False                           False                     False                       False
2                         True                             True                         True         False               False             False                         False                   False                       False                 False                           False                     False                       False
3                         True                             True                         True         False               False             False                         False                   False                       False                 False                           False                     False                       False
(Pdb) assert_frame_equal(actual_df, expected_df, check_like=True)
*** TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous
```

Comment: You are only showing us the columns that have booleans.  What about the other columns?

Comment: That just means one of the two frame has `pd.NA` at one position and the other has non-NA value at the same position. For example: `assert_frame_equal(pd.DataFrame({'a':[pd.NA]}),pd.DataFrame({'a':['b']}))`. In other words, your test is failing.

Comment: @TimRoberts that's because I misunderstood the error and because I have a couple hundred columns. I assumed that the error was expression a mismatch between boolean columns. I'm surprised to learn that a type mismatch in assert_frame_equals causes an exception other then an AssertionError.

Comment: While this works as expected in a test, i.e. throws some error when there is a mismatch, the error is more likely a bug in `assert_frame_equal`. It should assert the same error as in the case where the different values are both non-NA.